# Unable to connect jsjac to openfire

Tags: reverse-proxy, openfire, basichttpbinding, jsjac

I am trying to connect jsjac to openfire server. with very little success of course.

I have a apache server which redirects requests to my front end jsps hosted in a tomcat within eclipse and also binds requests to XMPP server.

Here is my virtual host mapping in config file:

ServerName ualbanybook.com
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPass /miniFaceBook http://localhost:8080/miniFaceBook
ProxyPassReverse /miniFaceBook http://localhost:8080/miniFaceBook
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /http-bind/ http://localhost:8181/http-bind/ [P]

The next image shows both the request url and error code on trying to register.
[image: error]

The next snapshot of snapshot of chrome dev tool shows that the request to register was indeed sent and the browser reciE[image]ved a response 200 OK.

I have configured port 8181 for http-binding in openfire.
Any pointers/help will be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: in host file , i have mapped ualbanychat.com to localhost . All servers are running on local host

Answer (score 0):

All these settings started later after clearing chrome cache. Also connected ijab later.
These settings can also serve as a guide to someone looking to setup openfire to a web client.